# Check if iis module exist by appcmd

Tags: powershell, iis, deployment, web-config

I need to check if my custom IIS module is installed for my site.
I run command bellow:

```
C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config 'mySite' /section:system.webServer/modules /[name="myModuleName"]
```

And see the error:

> ERROR ( message:The attribute "[name=myModuleName]" is not supported
>   in the current command usage. )

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure only `set`/`get`/`add` supports the `[name="value"]` filter syntax, not `list`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am creating script in order to add module or change type if this module already exists. How can I check it?

Comment: Use PowerShell and check if the module is in modules.

Comment: @LexLi I've created custom managed module(create and sign assembly). Could you please say which commands can I use in order to check it?

Comment: Use `get` instead of `list`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen appcmd doesn't support get for config object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on current versions of IIS (7 and higher), then why not just use the IIS Admin or Web Admin cmdlets, vs app command for this effort?

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=win10-ps
>
> https://octopus.com/blog/iis-powershell
>
> https://blogs.iis.net/jeonghwan/iis-powershell-user-guide-comparing-representative-iis-ui-tasks

```
# [IIS] Configure Module elements and properties which are configured in globalModules section 

# Case1: List all native modules
(Get-WebConfiguration //globalmodules).collection -PSPath iis:

# Case4: List all of enabled modules from 'server' level
(get-webconfiguration //modules -PSPath iis:).collection -PSPath iis:

# Case5: Get the attributes for a specific module
$modules=(get-webconfiguration //modules -PSPath iis:).collection
$modules | foreach {if ($_.name -eq "cgiModule") { $_.attributes | select name, value}}
```

Comment: No worries. It's good to know all possible options available to see what works best in a given use case.

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below command to achieve your requirement:

```
appcmd.exe list config "{yoursitename}" -section:system.webServer/modules /text:[name='myModuleName'].type
```

[image]

Comment: it works in cmd, in powerShell we need put  /text:[name='myModuleName'].type in quotes. Thank you so much.

Comment: It returns value when module is installed, but I also need to handle case when module isn't installed. This command returns an error.